# any of the Browser is not opening, when i execute the script using Robot framework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAzGR.png)I just started to learn the Robot framework, when I execute the script, I don't know why, none of the browsers are opening, please find below for my environment details:-

1. I am using Python2.7 and Pycharm IDE to write the script
2. Operating System :- windows 10
3. Browsers (Firefox (Version:- 55(64 bit)), Chrome (verion 62 (64 bit)), and Microsoft edge browser )
4. Web drivers :- I am using the latest one (geckodriver-v0.19.0-win64, chromedriver_win32)
5. Please find my script below :-

   ```
   ***Settings***
   Documentation This is some basic info about whole suite Library Selenium2Library

   ***Variables***

   ***Test Cases***
   User must Sign in to check out 
   [Documentation] 
   This is some basic info about test 
   [Tags] 
   Smoke 
   OPEN BROWSER https://www.amazon.com CLOSE BROWSER

   ***Keywords***
   ```

Please help me solve this issue, since I am beginner, I am not able to find the root cause of this error

Comment: *** Settings ***
Documentaion This is some basic information about the whole suite
Library Selenium2Library


*** Variables ***


*** Test Cases ***
User should be required to sign in when checking out
 [Documention] This is some basic information about the test
 [Tags] Smoke
 Open Browser  http://www.amazon.com 
 sleep  3s
 Close Browser


*** Keywords ***

Comment: So you dont have at least two spaces between Open Browser and then URL? if not, you really need to look into RF more to get a basic understanding.

Comment: Please show the errors that you are getting.

Comment: i have given 2 space in the script, there are no errors thrown by the script as well , it is just getting stuck, please find the screenshot, i have attached with the question, Thank you, helping me.

Comment: Hi all, Thank you for helping me, i found why it was causing error, i was using 32 bit python and 64 bit pycharm, after re-installing with 64 bit python, it started working, Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly are getting lots of errors when you try to run your script.

The most obvious error is that you only have a single space between your keywords and their arguments. For example, you must have two or more spaces between `OPEN BROWSER` and `https://www.amazon.com`.